# Google Play Store internal test - app stuck on splash screen

Tags: google-play

I have created an internal test for an app using the Google Play Console and sent the hyperlink to a test user.  However, once the app is installed on the tester's phone and the Open button is tapped it gets stuck on the splash screen and will not go any further.  The tester has tried restarting the phone, Force Stop the Google Play app, Clear Data and Clear Cache for Google Play app, uninstall/reinstall the app.  None of these have helped.  What would cause this behavior?  What steps should I take next to debug/resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you using Retrofit to make API calls? Are you using proguard / R8 to obfuscate your code?

Comment: Neither.  It appears that some code related to animation is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by putting try block before runApp(MyApp()) in main

```
void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      try {
        final InitialController _initialController = Get.put(InitialController(), permanent: true);
        final BasketController _basketController = Get.put(BasketController(), permanent: true);
        //final BackInterceptorController _backInterceptorController = Get.put(BackInterceptorController(), permanent: true);
        await _initialController.tokenInit();
      } catch (e) {
        logger(e);
      }
      runApp(MyApp()); 
    }
```